# C# Creating an Event System with delegates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, delegates

I am making a game using Unity and creating a simple event system for it. The system allows subscribing to events with a callback delegate.

The code for the system is here:

```
public static class Events {

#region fields
public delegate void EventCallback();

public static Dictionary<Event, EventCallback> events;

public enum Event {
    PlayerDied,
    EnterGoal,
    ExitGoal
}
#endregion

static Events() {
    Reset();
}

public static void Reset() {
    events = new Dictionary<Event, EventCallback>();
}

public static void SubscribeToEvent(EventCallback callback, Event type) {

    if (!events.ContainsKey(type)) {
        events.Add(type, callback);
    } else {
        events[type] += callback;
    }
}

public static void OverrideSubscription(EventCallback callback, Event type) {

    if (!events.ContainsKey(type)) {
        events.Add(type, callback);
    } else {
        events[type] = callback;
    }
}
public static void UnsubscribeFromEvent(EventCallback callback, Event type) {
    if (events.ContainsKey(type)) {
        events[type] -= callback;
    }
}

public static void FireEvent(Event type) {

    if (!events.ContainsKey(type)) {
        return;
    }

    events[type]?.Invoke();
}
}
```

My problem is this:

Quite often in the game the object which subscribes to some event will be destroyed  (and therefore nullified) but the callbacks are still called.

To demonstrate this I created tests for it. The 2 tests below fail.

```
[Test]
    public void CallbackIsNotCalledAfterReassigning() {

        Events.SubscribeToEvent(callbacks.A, Events.Event.PlayerDied);

        // Reassign
        callbacks = new CallbackContainer();

        Events.FireEvent(Events.Event.PlayerDied);

        Assert.AreEqual(0, callbacks.a, "Test function was called after reassigning");
        Assert.AreEqual(0, a, "Old instance method is still being called");
    }

    [Test]
    public void CallbackIsNotCalledAfterNullifying() {

        Events.SubscribeToEvent(callbacks.A, Events.Event.PlayerDied);

        // Nullify
        callbacks = null;

        Events.FireEvent(Events.Event.PlayerDied);

        Assert.AreEqual(0, a, "Test function was not called");
    }
```

And the CallbackContainer class is here:

```
public class CallbackContainer {

    public int a, b, c;

    public CallbackContainer() {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;
    }

    public Action TestFunction;

    public void A() {
        EventsTest.a++;
        a++;
    }
    public void B() {
        EventsTest.b++;
        b++;
    }
    public void C() {
        EventsTest.c++;
        c++;
    }
}
```

Is there a workaround for this problem? Is there a better and more correct way to creating an event system?

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: Why dont you remove the callbacks in `OnDestroy` then?

Comment: @derHugo I didn't even think about it for some reason :/

Comment: btw you can save a bit resources for GC if instead of `events = new Dictionary<Event, EventCallback>();` you use `events.Clear();`

Comment: In line 28 of the first code example above - how can this work, using += on the Value of the Dictionary, when that value's type is the Delegate declared above. It seems to me that code does not add the callback-delegate to the event, but to the value of the dictionary, which is as i said, a Delegate method. The += operator shouldn't compile in that case. Am i right, or am i missing something? Thx!!

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten about Unitys own delegate OnDestroy which is called before an object is destyroyed or before another scene is loaded.